# Opencv image capture Pauses when Tkinter label is displayed. Need assistance with Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, tkinter, multiprocessing

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
from time import time
from TKinterMess import Display
import tkinter as tk

import multiprocessing

e = multiprocessing.Event()
p = None

#kassadin portrait image
needle_list = []
kassadin_img = cv2.imread('kassadin.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
darius_img = cv2.imread('darius.JPG', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)


#loop_time = time()
needle_list.append(kassadin_img)
needle_list.append(darius_img)
threshold = 0.5

def mainloop():
    root = tk.Tk()

def start_text_display(text):
    global p
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Display, args=(text, e))
    p.start()

def namestr(obj, namespace):
    return [name for name in namespace if namespace[name] is obj]

def Display(text):
    #root = tk.Tk()
    w = tk.Label(root, text=text, font="Arial 100", background='gray')
    w.master.overrideredirect(True)
    w.master.geometry("+700+0")
    w.master.lift()
    w.master.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
    w.master.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
    w.master.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.5)
    w.master.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', 'white')
    w.after(1750 , w.master.destroy)
    w.pack()
    root.mainloop()

def record_screen():
    while True:
        screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1645,800,1920,1080))
        screenshot = np.array(screenshot)

        screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        for needle in needle_list:
            x = namestr(needle, globals())
            results = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot, needle, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
            min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(results)
            top_left = max_loc
            bottom_right = (top_left[0] + needle.shape[1], top_left[1] + needle.shape[0])
            if max_val >= threshold:
                if str(x) == "['darius_img']":
                    cv2.rectangle(screenshot, top_left, bottom_right, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_4)
                    Display('Darius')
                elif str(x) =="['kassadin_img']":
                    cv2.rectangle(screenshot, top_left, bottom_right, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_4)
                    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Display, args=('Kassadin',))
                    p2.start()
                    p2.join()

            cv2.imshow(None, screenshot)

        #print('FPS {}'.format(1 / (time() - loop_time)))
        #loop_time = time()

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=record_screen)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Display, args=('Kassadin',))
    p2.start()

    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

In the `main` function when I run `Display` as a process then it works no problem, the text shows up on screen and image capture is active in the bottom right.

However when I want to call `Display` and run it as a process when it finds a match in `record_screen` then it doesn't work and still freezes the display window.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **do not mix** any GUI with OpenCV's `imshow`/`waitKey`. imshow/waitKey uses its own GUI processing. it may work but often it doesn't. -- you're generally confused as to how python's `multiprocessing` works. this code can't be fixed. too much wrong. please start with a proper guide/tutorial that explains how to use the module.

Comment: You can’t run tkinter code that spans two or more processes. All tkinter code must be in a single process.